# Generate the pdf file in PHPExcel using dompdf library

Tags: php, phpexcel

Using dompdf library generate the pdf file, while i opened that pdf file it shows failed to load content error. I set renderer path and renderer library given below.

$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf.php';
$rendererLibraryPath =                     name(**FILE**).'/../dompdf/libraries/dompdf/'.$rendererLibrary;

Comment: Open the file in a text editor, and look for any leading or trailing whitespace characters, BOM header, or plaintext PHP error messages in the body of the file.... and learn to do some basic debugging for yourself

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$rendererName = PHPExcel_Settings::PDF_RENDERER_DOMPDF;
$rendererLibrary = 'dompdf.php';
$rendererLibraryPath = dirname(__FILE__). 'libs/classes/dompdf' . $rendererLibrary;
```

Correct your PHP according to this

```
$file = "path_to_file";
$fp = fopen($file, "r") ;

header("Cache-Control: maxage=1");
header("Pragma: public");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=".$myFileName."");
header("Content-Description: PHP Generated Data");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Content-Length:' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
while (!feof($fp)) {
   $buff = fread($fp, 1024);
   print $buff;
}
exit;
```

Comment: i tried above this also but still i am facing the same problem.

Comment: You can try changing PHP

Comment: i change the php file as given above content  but still i am facing the same problem.

Comment: In this case I can not help you sorry

Answer (score 0):

Just had a similar error today but not with PHPExcel.

I had to populate a PDF with PHP and show it after, but I was always getting a "Failed to load PDF document" error from Chrome.

I don't know if it was the same problem, but in my case, PHP was reporting Notice and Warning errors, nothing too important, but because of that, the PDF was not able to load. Hiding the error solved my problem!

TL;DR : Try `error_reporting(E_STRICT);` on top of your PHP file (quick and dirty) or `exit;` before reading the file so you can see the errors and fix them.